# Can I use the default UIBarButton icons provided by Apple in other assets of my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

Like in UIButton  or a UIImageView etc..

If so how do I do that using the StoryBoard or in a Xib

I am able to use the default icons inside UIBarButton items but cannot look them up in normal buttons . A solution using Storyboard would be really nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In order to use them you need to extract them** using a handy little app called (fittingly enough) iOS Artwork Extractor.  I use it all the time when I want to mimic iOS system behaviours.

Download the Xcode project at:

https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor

**Or another way**:

The Other.artwork file is in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/ (you need the SDK).

Use the "iPhoneShop-1.3.jar" program -- available currently [here](http://www.modmyi.com/forums/skinning-themes-discussion/665281-iphoneshop-3-0-import-export-artwork-files-3-0-a.html) to extract all of the images into a directory.

```
java -jar iPhoneShop-1.3.jar ARTWORK Other.artwork EXPORT Other
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot use UIBarButtonItem on other as subview like UIButton. UIBarButtonItem can only over UINavigationBar.

Comment: Can they be used for UIBarButtonItems on the Toolbar too?

Comment: can use in UIToolbar